# Indexación condicional

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

La indexación condicional es una operación que permite seleccionar filas de un DataFrame o Series en función de una condición. La condición puede ser una expresión booleana, una cadena, un número o una lista.
Ejemplo.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Nombre": ["Juan", "Pedro", "María", "Luis"],
    "Edad": [25, 30, 20, 27]
})
df[df["Edad"].between(20, 25)]
```

devuelve.

```
    Nombre  Edad
0   Juan    25
2   María   20
```

La tilde **(~)** es un operador lógico que se utiliza para invertir el valor de un valor booleano. Es decir, si un valor booleano es True, **~** lo convierte en False y viceversa. En el contexto de la indexación condicional, **~** se puede utilizar para seleccionar filas que no cumplen con una condición.
Interpreto que, de  acuerdo con este concepto, si hacemos `df[~df["Edad"] > 25]`, me debería devolver laas filas del DataFrame en las que la edad es < 25. Ejecuto y me devuelve

Nombre  Edad

un DataFrame vacío, luego no estoy entendiendo bien este concepto.
En este caso, `~df["Edad"] > 25` es una condición booleana que es **True** si la edad es menor a 25 y **False** si la edad es mayor de 25, ya que el operador lógico (~) invierte el valor de un  valor booleano. ¿Qué es lo que no estoy entendiendo bien?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Precedencia

El operador "~", al igual que los operadores aritmeticos y el resto de operadores, tienen [precedencia](https://interactivechaos.com/es/manual/tutorial-de-python/precedencia-de-operadores). Es la prioridad que tiene un operador por encima de otros.

Por ejemplo en la cuenta `a + b * c - d`

Primero, resolvemos la multiplicación, ya que es la que tiene precedencia más alta dentro de la expresión. Luego la suma y la resta, de precedencia más baja.

##### Entonces, por que este comportamiento inesperado

Tenemos esta expresión: `~df["Edad"] > 25`, donde suceden muchas cosas.

Como "~" tiene más precedencia que ">", se resuelve primero ~df["Edad"]

Esto convierte implicitamente la serie "Edad" en booleano (equivalente a `.astype(bool)`). Los 0 son false, y el resto de numeros es True. Luego, como dijiste, invierte o "convierte los True en False y los False en True".

Luego aplica el operador ">". Y como los booleanos en Python son subclases de int, se pueden comparar como si fueran números (0 == False, 1 == True).

A continuación una muestra de como se va efectuando cada operación.

```
(~10 > 25) -> (~True  > 25) -> (False > 25) -> (0 > 25) -> False
(~0  > 25) -> (~False > 25) -> (True  > 25) -> (1 > 25) -> False
```

Lo que resulta, claramente, en un df vacío, ya que no hay forma, asumiendo que ~df["Edad"] devuelve una serie de booleanos, de que la condición de verdadero.

##### Solución

La precendencia de los operadores puede ser alterada usando parentesis. Probablemente, como usuario de Pandas, estés haciendo esto sin darte cuenta de lo que realmente sucede. Por ejemplo, al hacer `(a > b) & (b < c)`, notarás que los parentesis son obligatorios a la hora de esperar un buen funcionamiento.

En el caso de tu condición sería tan simple como escribirla usando parentesis:

```
~(df["Edad"] > 25)
```